# pandas pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp drop date info

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame of time series data, one column is tmstmp, dtype is datetime64[ns], the other column is some values.

```
In [35]: temp_df.head()
Out[35]:
               tmstmp  spd
0 2016-08-11 10:56:00    0
1 2016-08-11 10:56:00   20
2 2016-08-11 10:56:00   12
3 2016-08-11 10:56:00   23
4 2016-08-11 10:56:00   30

In [36]: temp_df.dtypes
Out[36]:
tmstmp    datetime64[ns]
spd                int64
dtype: object
```

I want to drop the date info from tmstmp column, i.e, only keep hr/min/sec, because I only care about the value at a specific time of a day, don't care about which day. And finally I want to plot it. Which type should I cast it to? (And I suppose I should cast it to some type that can be plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need convert column to [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) and then [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
temp_df['times'] = temp_df['tmstmp'].dt.time
temp_df.plot(x='times', y='spd')
```